# Reuse Angular 2 service in Chrome extension

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension

I have an Angular 2 app that talks to a webserver via an Angular service (By Angular Service I mean the client side code that talks to the webserver, which in Angular lingo also called 'Service'. [example](http://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html)))

I would like to build a chrome extension that integrates with the address bar (`chrome.omnibox.onInputEntered.addListener`) and that reuses the service from my angular app so that the chrome ext will use the same code to talk to the server side service as the Angular app.
The Angular Service is written in TypeScript and uses Angular's http module and rxjs.

Is it common to do so? what's the best practices for refactoring the service such that it's usable in both targets?

Comment: It's not clear why you think you need to refactor anything.

Comment: I'm a noob with all involved topics so I guess I was looking for examples because I don't know where to start. I thought it needed refactoring because currently it's part of the Angular project, and since now both project depend on it, it should become a separate module? Also, not clear how to bootstrap angular 2 as part of the chrome extension in a minimal form without UI just to sustain the service

Comment: I mean in both cases your client code communicates to a webserver so there's no apparent need to refactor anything.

Comment: OK I think I see why my question was misunderstood. Of course the server side service is the same and doesn't need refactoring. But the question was about the client side piece of code that talks to the server side service - I want to reuse this across Angular and the Chrome extension so that the chrome ext will use the same code to talk to the server side service as the Angular app. It's confusing because the client side code that talks to the server side service is also called Service in Angular lingo: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify Angular Service vs Server side Service

Comment: I haven't used Angular but the service seems to be just another javascript code that can run in a browser, meaning you can use it similarly. Your extension will have a background/event page which is basically a hidden window where all your code runs just like it would run a normal tab + chrome.omnibox listeners.